# If exists two-form not null in $S$, so $S$ is orientable

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, surfaces, parametrization, orientation

I need to prove that, being $S$ a regular surface,

> If exists a two-form not null in $S$, so $S$ is orientable.

Here, I need to use estricly the basic definition for orientability, ie, any two parametrizations $\psi:U\to \psi(U)\subset S$ and $\varphi:V\to \varphi(V)\subset S$ are s.t. $\psi(U)\cap\varphi(V)=\emptyset$ or the jacobian of the parametrization changing is always $>0$.

I was trying to follow this line of thought:

> In a point of $S$ bellowing to two parametrizations, if I have some $w=w_1\wedge w_2$ not null, so when I take the vectors of the basis induced by these parametrizations, $w$ may be positive or negative, so the basis have same orientation.

Maybe it can be right, but in this case the two-form must be not null in any point. I'd like to know how can I do this to a two-form not null (ie, not null in all points).

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this context, "not null" means "not null at *any* point", not "not null at *every* point" (the result would not be true with the latter meaning).  In other words, you are meant to assume that $w$ is nonzero at every point, and so your argument (with more details filled in) works and you are done.

Comment: Many thanks, Eric.